# Proper citation for industry resource

Tags: citation-style

Following on from my question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30769/how-to-acknowledge-oneself-as-the-author-of-materials-created-in-industry-resear) where I develop industry resources under the auspices of my company, I am wondering what would be a suggested citation format that I can include in the publication itself (on the copyright and disclaimer page). This would be a further claim on my authorship of these resources.

An example of a resource is "Ten Key Considerations when Terminating Employees". The resource is available in hardcopy and electronically. My company name and logo appear on the first page. My company can be considered the publisher of this resource.

Answer (score 3):

I mostly refer to industry resources as technical reports, and as I use BibTeX, I use the `@techreport` citation for that. If they're simply websites, I use `@misc`. Many citation styles will produce different results in how the reference is formatted, but I can think of the following example (that combines both the report and website, but you could leave the website out if that's not wanted):

`J. Baker, 2014. "Ten Key Considerations when Terminating Employees". Technical report of <Company Name>. From: http://website.com/, accessed <date>.`

Instead of technical report it could also be 'whitepaper' or 'brochure' or any other type, if you want to specify this.